# Problems Copying Filtered Data To New Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I am using this code to filter a database, and then copy the resulting filtered data to a worksheet in a second workbook.

```
 With ws_sched
    Set srng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row, .Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
        srng.AutoFilter _
        Field:=2, _
        Criteria1:=trgt_date, _
        VisibleDropDown:=False
    'srng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws_data.Range("A1")
    srng.Copy
    ws_data.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

'ws_sched' is the raw database that is filtered.
'ws_data' is the destination worksheet in a second workbook.

The filter works, but the copy and paste leaves only the header row of the source database (1st row of many rows of filtered data).

Is anyone able to help me resolve the issue as to why my filtered data isn't being transferred?

The above code reflects the changes I have made from my original code based on my understanding of Thiago's suggestion. This still only copies the header row and no filtered data.

Comment: Thiago, thanks for your suggestion. I have tried to adapt my code based on my understanding of your suggestion, but it still only results in the header row being copied. None of the filtered data is copied.

Comment: My adapted code can be seen in my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be you only have the header in `ws_sched` column A, the one that gives you the rows *depth* of `srng`, which therefore is set to a one-row `range`

you can prove that by adding some `Msgbox srng.Address` statement right after `Set srng =...`

So you have two ways:

- choose a different column to take data rows *depth* from

  in this case I'd go with column "B" since this is the one you seem to want to filter on

  ```
  Set srng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row, .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
  ```
- infer data rows *depth* by means of UsedRange

  in this case you only need to change the *copying* statement a follows:

  ```
  Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(2).EntireRow, srng.EntireColumn).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws_data.Range("A1")
  ```

Finally you may have the case where column A is *completely* blank, i.e. without even the header. in this case you should just shift all your code to beging with column B

```
        Set srng = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row, .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
            srng.AutoFilter _
            Field:=1, _
            Criteria1:=">=2", _
            VisibleDropDown:=False
        srng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws_data.Range("A1")
```

Comment: That indeed was the problem. It simply was solved by a second set of eyes. Column A was blank, so using a populated column B was the ticket to success.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Several difference answers, with each providing a valuable learning experience. That alone is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to PasteSpecial the copied data instead of informing the destination as you're doing now

Answer (score 0):

This VBA code will help you to Filtered data into other Sheet.

Sub copy_filtered_data()

Worksheets("Data Input").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _         Destination:=Worksheets("Results").Range("A1")

End Sub

NB : You can use this one with Autofilter code also.

Comment: Thank you Rajesh. I used your suggestion at another point in my project where I was having similar problems and it too worked wonderfully.

Comment: Nice to hear from you,, it's my pleasure,, please keep asking. ☺